# How to send email which converts view in pdf and then attach it in the mail in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to send the email with attachment of pdf.
The pdf should be the view.
So, the view should be converted into pdf and then attaches to the mail and send it.

Code of Mail Function.

```
$data = array('invoice_basic_data'=>$invoice_basic_data,'invoice_data'=>$invoice_data,'email'=>$email);
Mail::send('finalprint', $data, function($message) {
    $email=request('email');
    $message->to($email, )->subject('Your Invoice');
    $message->from('xyz@gmail.com','Jaydeep Rajgor');
    $pdf=PDF::loadHtml(URL::to('finalprint'));
    $message->attachData($pdf->output(),'abc.pdf',['mime'=>'application/pdf']);
});
```

It sends the mail as an attachment but attachment has only the URL of view finalprint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is to pass the rendered content to the PDF library:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadHtml(view('finalprint')->render());
```

Or, is it possible that the PDF library to have a `loadUrl` (or such) method which can be used in your case:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadUrl(URL::to('finalprint'));
```

Comment: I have used loadView()

Answer (score 0):

You can use dompdf package

[DomPdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf)

After making instance of dompdf, use this to attach as pdf in Mail::send().

`$message->attachData($pdf->output(), 'filename.pdf');`